# Guardar Fotografia en Modo Horizontal clase ExifInterface

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, cámara

Tengo una aplicación en android, cuando tomo la fotografia, y cada vez que la muestro en un imageView la imagen siempre la cambia de orientación existe la manera de guardarla en la orientación que yo quiera?

Se puede tomar una fotografia en android studio y guardarla como imagen horizontal? Aun que esta sea tomada como Vertical o Horizontal?

Utilizando la clase ExitInterface o algo por el estilo?

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

por norma general las cámaras hacen las fotos en landscape o paisaje, es decir, si tomas la foto en portrait o retrato, las fotos resultantes se girarán 90 grados. En este caso, el software de la cámara debe rellenar los datos Exif con la orientación en la que debe verse la foto.

Ten en cuenta que la siguiente solución depende del fabricante del software/dispositivo de la cámara, por lo que funcionará en la mayoría de los casos, pero no es una solución 100% segura, aunque a mi me da resultado siempre.

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                     ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

switch(orientation) {

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

    default:
        break;
}
```

Y el metodo para rotar la imagen

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                               matrix, true);
}
```

Espero que solucione tu problema o que sea esto lo que esperabas.

Saludos.

Comment: Tengo una duda,     case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
esa linea a que haces referencia?

Comment: Hace referencia a una foto en modo portrait o retrato en la que es asi realmente, es decir, el teléfono en vertical sin rotacion alguna.

Comment: En pocas palabra si cae dentro de esa seccion me mostrara la imagen verticalmente o podra mostra solo las que estas en modo vertical?

Comment: Eso es, si cae dentro de esa sección se mostrará verticalmente la foto. Lo mejor es que lo pruebes por ti mismo y veas como funciona. Debugea el código paso a paso y mira que hace y como. Parece una tontería esto último pero ayuda una barbaridad. Saludos.